# Make vim / curl recognize https:// links

Tags: vim, curl, https

I recently noticed vim/vimdiff can open links (using curl, it seems), which is an awesome feature.
I wanted to use it today, like this:

vimdiff deps https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/v2.0.10/deps

But the `https://` does not seem to trigger this awesome mechanism too. There is no authentication on this page, I think `https://` is just there to provide data encryption. How can I force vim to recognize the `https://` protocol?

Comment: I'm looking through the netrw plugin source, which handles http files, and it doesn't handle https; I'm seeing if there's an easy way to fix, but it seems it's not as simple as adding a `,https://` like I've done for other things.

Comment: Then maybe I should report a bug, but where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mailed the author (drchip) here is his answer :

> Hello,
>
> Netrw v144b already supports https (you may get it from
>   http://drchip.0sites.net/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW).
>
> Thank you, Charles Campbell

The website has since moved and can currently be found at http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

To install it, I just had to download the .vba.gz file, unpack it, open it with vim, then follow the instructions (source the file with `:so %`).

My .vim is under version control, you can see the commit here : https://github.com/greg0ire/dotvim/commit/bfbe569ce070383c9f0a7b966ad23a35eefb651f

Comment: @jw013 : I forgot, done

Answer (score 4):

As I said in a comment, the netrw plugin, which handles `http://`, doesn't handle `https://` (this from looking at the plugin code). I went into the code and got `https://` working (no guarantees it's bug-free, but it worked for the couple sites I tried). I've created a pair of patches, for [`netrw.vim`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/834235/) and [`netrwPlugin.vim`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/834260/). Here's how to apply them, keeping the originals untouched and the patched versions in your local configuration:

- Make sure you have a `~/.vim/autoload` and `~/.vim/plugin` directory.
- Download the patches, remember where you saved them (I'll assume it's at `~/.vim/patches/netrw.patch` and `~/.vim/patches/netrwPlugin.patch`)

```
cp /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/autoload/netrw.vim ~/.vim/autoload
cp /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim ~/.vim/plugin
patch ~/.vim/autoload/netrw.vim ~/.vim/patches/netrw.patch
patch ~/.vim/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim ~/.vim/patches/netrwPlugin.patch
```

This works on my vim, 7.3, hopefully yours too. If not, use the changes as a guide and see if you can hack it.

---

In case the pastebins disappear, here they are:

netrwPlugin.patch

```
56c56
<  au BufReadCmd   ftp://*,rcp://*,scp://*,http://*,dav://*,davs://*,rsync://*,sftp://* exe "silent doau BufReadPre ".fnameescape(expand("<amatch>"))|call netrw#Nread(2,expand("<amatch>"))|exe "silent doau BufReadPost ".fnameescape(expand("<amatch>"))
---
>  au BufReadCmd   ftp://*,rcp://*,scp://*,http://*,https://*,dav://*,davs://*,rsync://*,sftp://*   exe "silent doau BufReadPre ".fnameescape(expand("<amatch>"))|call netrw#Nread(2,expand("<amatch>"))|exe "silent doau BufReadPost ".fnameescape(expand("<amatch>"))
```

netrw.patch

```
682c682
<    if choice =~ "^.*[\/]$" && b:netrw_method != 5 && choice !~ '^http://'
---
>    if choice =~ "^.*[\/]$" && b:netrw_method != 5 && choice !~ '^http://' && choice !~ '^https://'
835c835
<    elseif     b:netrw_method  == 5
---
>    elseif     b:netrw_method  == 5 || b:netrw_method  == 50
850c850,854
<       exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape("http://".g:netrw_machine.b:netrw_fname,1)." ".g:netrw_http_xcmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)
---
>       if b:netrw_method  == 5
>        exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape("http://".g:netrw_machine.b:netrw_fname,1)." ".g:netrw_http_xcmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)
>       else 
>        exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape("https://".g:netrw_machine.b:netrw_fname,1)." ".g:netrw_http_xcmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)
>       endif
853c857,861
<       exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)." ".shellescape("http://".g:netrw_machine.b:netrw_fname,1)
---
>       if b:netrw_method == 5 
>        exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)." ".shellescape("http://".g:netrw_machine.b:netrw_fname,1)
>       else 
>        exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)." ".shellescape("https://".g:netrw_machine.b:netrw_fname,1)
>       endif
865c873,877
<      exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)." ".shellescape("http://".g:netrw_machine.netrw_html,1)
---
>      if b:netrw_method == 5
>       exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)." ".shellescape("http://".g:netrw_machine.netrw_html,1)
>      else 
>       exe s:netrw_silentxfer."!".g:netrw_http_cmd." ".shellescape(tmpfile,1)." ".shellescape("https://".g:netrw_machine.netrw_html,1)
>      endif
1565a1578
>   let httpsurm = '^https://\([^/]\{-}\)\(/.*\)\=$'
1598a1612,1618
>   " Method#5.5: https://user@hostname/...path-to-file {{{3
>   elseif match(a:choice,httpsurm) == 0
> "   call Decho("https://...")
>    let b:netrw_method = 50
>    let g:netrw_machine= substitute(a:choice,httpsurm,'\1',"")
>    let b:netrw_fname  = substitute(a:choice,httpsurm,'\2',"")
> 
7075c7095
<   if w:netrw_method == 2 || w:netrw_method == 5
---
>   if w:netrw_method == 2 || w:netrw_method == 5 || w:netrw_method == 50
```

Comment: The netrwPlugin.patch fails to apply on my version of the file. I'm using Fedora, which ships vim 7.3, and I tried to apply the patch "manually" by editing the file but I get strange errors : `Erreur détectée en traitant function netrw#Nread..netrw#NetRead..<SNR>35_NetrwMethod :
ligne   86 :
E121: Variable non définie : httpsurm
E116: Arguments invalides pour la fonction match(a:choice,httpsurm) == 0
E15: Expression invalide : match(a:choice,httpsurm) == 0
"NetrwMessage"  --Le tampon est vide--` I mailed about this thread to the address I found here : https://github.com/vim-scripts/netrw.vim

Comment: Got the same problem at work with Ubuntu, but with a different error : curl complains about dav not being enabled. Here is the content of my netrwPlugin file : http://hastebin.com/jibenaluwi.xml

Comment: The plugin author answered me, he told me the latest version had support for https:// I should find it here : http://drchip.0sites.net/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW and try it later.